# How do I insert # character in echo statement for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

When I include the # glyph in my statement, to return to an anchor on the page, the PHP code fails.

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve this issue, escaping PHP characters, writing JavaScript functions and the list goes on.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $_POST = array();
    echo "<script>window.location.href='Contact_Us.php#myForm'</script>";
    } else {
    unset($_POST);
}
```

There are no error messages.
The page appears to refresh and the code to unset the POST variables fails.

Comment: Yes so isn't that what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Why aren't you using [header](http://php.net/header)?

Comment: What do you mean by `the PHP code fails`? Does it give an error? A `#` won't be sent to the server.

Comment: _“The page appears to refresh and the code to unset the POST variables fails.”_ - if the JavaScript code manages to “refresh” the page, then that will be a GET request - so there won’t be any POST data afterwards to begin with. Not sure what you see “failing” here and how … the whole problem description is really rather bad. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do things that way simply drop out of PHP instead of trying to echo things.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $_POST = array();
?>
<script>window.location.href='Contact_Us.php#myForm'</script>
<?php
    } else {
    unset($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Fails to unset POST in this effort.

Comment: Why do you think it would? The `unset` of `$_POST` is in the `else`. If the `isset` is satisfied you will never reach the else. Not with my change nor with your original code. Simply isn't possible.

Comment: What is happening is that the location in the previous code is reached w/o error and the $_POST data is cleared however, when the # character is introduced, the page reloads and maintains the $_POST data with it.